# Kinect Explorer and runtime variables not installed with V1 installer on win8/VS2010 or VS11

Tags: kinect, windows-8

Windows 8 build 8102, Kinect SDK V1.0

And so it begins that I had a win 8 box setup for Kinect development with the beta 2 sdk. Everything ran fine.

I then decided to upgrade to V1 once I saw I could still develop without having to wait on my K4W hardware to get here. I uninstalled beta2 backed up all of my projects and installed V1. I thought everything was going well until I noticed VS2010 couldn't find the reference for Kinect (I know it is microsoft.kinect instead of ms.research.kinect).

So I manually found the reference in my program files and went on my merry way. My project built and ran fine. I then watched the new version of the quickstarts and wanted to see this Kinect Explorer in action.

It wasn't on my system. So I uninstalled and re-installed, read every news article on the subject looking for a seperate installer etc. It's not there.

After asking on twitter I then decided to do a refresh (I love this feature of win8) and re-install with just V1. That didn't work either.

So now I am stuck. I can't get Kinect Explorer I can't follow along with the quickstarts etc.

Anyone else found a way out of this problem?
Is there a seperate installer for Kinect Explorer? 
Does this just not work with Win8? Beta 2 did!

Thanks
David Bates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reset the PC not refresh it. 
There must have been some settings leftover from beta2 that messed with the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Kinect explorer is the new version of "Skeleton view" in the MSR version of Kinect for Windows (the beta versions). You will only get Kinect explorer when installing the current/final build of Kinect for Windows.

There are also breaking changes between builds, as documented, and as you found out the namespaces change. If you update the namespaces in your project when using the current KfW software you should be fine to build and run your application.

Comment: While I can build my projects. my question was simply about Kinect Explorer. I may be using the wrong terminology but the Kinect Explorer is a sample app that should be installed with the SDK. I am missing all of the Sample apps and viewers. So I can't follow along with the examples.